# Replace all uses of an instruction to delete with an Undef value at llvm?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I would like to replace all uses of an instruction, which is a function call that I want to delete, with an Undef value.

First, I declare my undef value like this

```
UndefValue *undefval;
```

and then I try to replace all the uses of my instruction

```
currentInst->replaceAllUsesWith(undefval);
```

**currentInst** is an

```
Instruction* currentInst;
```

value which refers to my current instruction. This causes LLVM to produce the following error ans assertion:

> opt: /home/troulakis/Documents/LLVM_Project/llvm/llvm/lib/IR/Value.cpp:332: void llvm::Value::replaceAllUsesWith(llvm::Value *): Assertion `New->getType() == getType() && "replaceAllUses of value with new value of different type!"' failed.
>
> 0 0x160e678 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(_IO_FILE*)
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x160e678) 1 0x160fbdb
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x160fbdb) 2 0x7f7752596340 __restore_rt
>   (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x10340) 3 0x7f77515aacc9
>   gsignal (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x36cc9) 4 0x7f77515ae0d8
>   abort (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x3a0d8) 5 0x7f77515a3b86
>   (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2fb86) 6 0x7f77515a3c32
>   (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2fc32) 7 0x15be04f
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x15be04f) 8 0x7f775136fda7 (anonymous
>   namespace)::MyPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&)
>   (../../../Release+Asserts/lib/PassRAF.so+0x6da7) 9 0x15a1ab4
>   llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&)
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x15a1ab4) 10 0x15a1d3b
>   llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&)
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x15a1d3b) 11 0x15a22d7
>   llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&)
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x15a22d7) 12 0x5af6db main
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x5af6db) 13 0x7f7751595ec5 __libc_start_main
>   (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec5) 14 0x59f559 _start
>   (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x59f559)
>
> Stack dump:
>
> 1. Program arguments: opt -load ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/PassRAF.so -time-passes -instnamer
>      -PassRAF
> 2. Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module ''.
> 3. Running pass 'R A F' on function '@main'
>
> ./PassRAF: line 15:  7227 Aborted                 (core dumped)

Any ideas what's wrong? I have wrong declare of undef value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write this:

```
UndefValue *undefval;
```

You're just declaring a pointer of type `UndefValue`, and not storing anything in it. Instead, you need to get an instance of `UndefValue` for the type of the instruction you want to replace, using the [`UndefValue::get`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1UndefValue.html#a4ae5ff22b700a42bcc5d889233721335) factory function. Something like this:

```
currentInst->replaceAllUsesWith(UndefValue::get(currentInst->getType())
```